# Amazon EC2 Windows Ubuntu

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to AWS EC2 so that I make this post for some questions.

1) Right now, I am considering running some script on the server. I use two tools usually. One is a software can only be used in Windows. The other is just python. Should I open two instances, one for windows, one for ubuntu? Or just one instance of Windows with Git Bash installed? I want to be cost and performance efficiently.

2) I am not going to use the script very often (usually 2-3 hours per day or 10-12 hours per week). Therefore, is it easy to schedule those jobs automatically across the instances? I mean it can automatically turn off and restart given appropriate time.

3) Some of the script involves web scraping. I am also wondering if it is ok to switch IP address every time I run the script. Mainly, it is for python script.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1) Well, off course, the less instances you have, the less you will pay. Python can run on Windows, I just don't know how tricky it would be to make it work in your case. It all depends on what you are running and what are your management requirements. Those script languages were originally designed for Unix environments, so people usually runs it on those kind of systems, so running it in Windows may be a little unpleasant. Anyway, I don't think you should ask someone else it, you should figure it out yourself what suits you best.

2) AWS doesn't have a scheduler for EC2 (stop, starting, etc, given date/times/recurrence). It's something that I miss on it too. So, to achieve something like this you have some options.

- Turning your temporary instance into an auto-scaling group of 1 instance, and scheduling policies to scale it in to zero instances and scale it out to 1 instance again when you want. The problem with this approach is: if you can't be sure how long it will take for your job to be completed, then you have a problem, off course, because those scheduled actions are based in fixed date/times. One solution for this would be the temporary instance itself changing the autoscaling group configuration to zero instances via API when it has finished. (In this case, you would just have a scale out scheduled policy, to launch the instance, leaving the termination of it to be done 'manually', via auto-scaling group configuration handling from inside the temporary instance). But be aware that auto-scaling is very tricky for begginers, and you should go throught the documentation before using it. (For exemple, each time you scale in and out you instances, they're terminated, not just stopped, and you lose every data on it.)
- Not using auto-scaling group, having a regular instance, and scheduling all those actions from outside it via API. It could be from your Windows (master) instance. In this case, the master would start the temporary instance via API, which would run its things and then turn itself off when it had finished. Otherwise, the master instance would have to keep polling the temporary one somehow to know when the jobs are done and it can be shutdown from outside.
- There are probably more complicated ways for doing this (Elastic Beanstalk crons, maybe).

I think, in this case, the more simple, the better. So, I would stick to the option 2). You will only need to figure how to install and use AWS CLI on Windows and manage IAM credentials and permissions to provide your CLI  access enough for it to do what it needs.

3) If you don't assign an Elastic IP to your instance, you will get a different IP each time you stop and start it, so this is, by default, what you want. In auto-scaling, this is the only way, you can't even assign a fixed IP to instances.

I hope I could help you a little bit.